# Query for searching in database based on text box and a string

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

So I'm trying to search my database using a username input through a text box and a password stored as a string (the user inputs their password into a text box and some operations are done to it for encryption, the encrypted password is then stored as a string; this string is what I use to search the database since the database has the encrypted passwords stored in it)

The command works fine for the username string input through the text box, but when I use the derived password string directly it doesn't work. I think a syntax error in the following line of code is giving trouble:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
    ("SELECT * FROM UserInfo 
    WHERE [User ID] = '" & txtLoginID.Text & "' 
    AND [EncryptedPassword] = '" & EncPasswordString & "' ", con)
```

EncPasswordString is the string that stores the encrypted password that was acquired through various operations. I need to compare this string to the EncryptedPassword in the database. Thank you!

This is what I've been using to acquire EncPasswordSting:

```
        i = 0

    While (PLength > 0)
        charofP = sHex(i)
        ascvalue = Strings.Asc(chartest)
        decvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(ascvalue)
        shiftdecvalue = decvalue + 1
        asctochar = ChrW(shiftdecvalue)
        emptychararray(i) = asc
        i = i + 1
        PLength = PLength - 1
    End While

    EncPasswordString = Convert.ToString(emptychararray)
```

Comment: Instead of jamming the SQL string into the OldDBCommand, make it a string variable.   When it is built during runtime, you'll be able to get the value in the debugger.  Try pasting the resultant SQL string into an SQL window...and debug it from there.

Comment: I will try that but I would really like to just edit the line given above.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bad diagnosis.  What's the error you're getting?  If you're just getting a blank resultset, then it's not a syntax error.  Also, Sql Injection is bad, blah blah blah.  If you don't know what that is, look it up and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: Look at your character sets.  If you're entering text as ASCII but the string is stored as UTF-X that could cause some issues.

Comment: The error is: " An unhandled exception of the type 'System.Data.OleDB.OleDbException' occured in System.Data.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offcourse it will not work at all. As u said that the Password is Encrypted. in your words ("but when I use the derived password string directly it doesn't work.") You have two options to validate and make it work:

1. `Encrypt` the Input Password and Compare with password in DB.
2. `Decrypt` the Password after retrieval and compare with input Password.

Please share your `SQL command text` that you have while debug.

Comment: So right now I'm trying to follow your method 1: encrypt the input password and compare it to a bank of already encrypted passwords from my database. I successfully encrypted the input password and stored it in a string (EncPasswordString), but what I can't do is use that string in the sql statement that reads what's on the database. I think it has something to do with not have the .text but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can!just use the encrypted input password as regular text. Let me explain..When u are storing the Password you are encrypting using some algorithm right! Now when you entering the Password in a TextBox and clicking on submit just encrypt the input Password with the algorithm that you use while storing the password and after encrypting the input password just compare it as usual string with the stored value into the DB. that set..! Please let me know do u need any clearance..! :)